# Php string not working in Wordpress Functions.php (trying to fetch 1st category for each blog that post appears in the sidebar)

Tags: functions, categories, link-category, function-exists

I am trying to fetch 1st category for each blog post that appears in the sidebar of any blogpost landing page.

I tried multiple options to add the 2nd block code to the 1st block at the line `".wp_get_post_categories ($post_id)."` but I could not find any solution.

Please help me with that and if you need closer to the code just let me know.

**1st Block**

```php
$related_blog .="<div class='related-blog'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <a href=".get_the_permalink().">
                            
                                    <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 blog-image'>
                                        <img src=".$image_related[0].">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 blog-text'>
                                        <strong><p class='related-blog-title'>".get_the_title()."</p></strong>
                                </a>
                                <span class='related-blog-sidebar-content '>".substr(get_the_content(),0,250)."...</span>
                                
                                <p class='related-blog-sidebar-category'>
                                ".wp_get_post_categories ($post_id)."                               
                                </p>
                                
                                <a class='related-blog-sidebar-link' href=".get_the_permalink().">Read More
                                </a>

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>";
```

**2nd Block**

```php
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<a  href="<?php echo get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID); ?> ">
<?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?> </a>
```

Comment: Is the 1st code block inside some kind of post loop? Is the `$post_id` on it the ID of a related post?

Comment: Yes, it is a loop. Actually, i am trying to call the post category in sidebar blog links.

Comment: Your code blocks are incomplete, for example in block 1 you append a value to `$related_blog` but you never show where that variable comes from, how it's used, or where the code is located. You also say that it doesn't do what you want it to do, but you never said what it does instead. You also didn't say where the second block of code is.

Comment: Also the categories on a post don't have an order, there is no first second or last category, they're usually sorted alphabetically or in the order of the term IDs when shown

Comment: The first block code is written in functions.php
It is used for the blog sidebar 

Check this thread 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388823/php-string-not-working-in-wordpress-functions-php

Here I have placed a particular code block that I need to insert to fetch the 1st category of that blog which is appearing in the sidebar also I want the name and hyperlink of it.