# Php string not working in Wordpress Functions.php

Tags: php, functions, categories, link-category

How to pass the following code.

```
<div> <?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
      <a  href="<?php echo get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID); ?> ">
      <?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?> </a>
</div>
```

In the function.php file's following code.

```
$related_blog .="//want to pass the above code here.";
```

For detailed description visit here: [click here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386889/php-string-not-working-in-wordpress-functions-php-trying-to-fetch-1st-category?noredirect=1#comment562213_386889)

Comment: If your question does not get much attention, you should improve it by editing it so that it's clearer and easier to understand, do not repost it as a new duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to append the string:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
$related_blog .= '<div><a  href="'. get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID). '">'. $category[0]->cat_name.' </a></div>';
?>
```